# Using Mockito, how do I test a 'finite loop' with a boolean condition?

Tags: mocking, mockito

Using Mockito, how do I test a 'finite loop' ?

I have a method I want to test that looks like this:

```
public void dismissSearchAreaSuggestions()
{
    while (areSearchAreaSuggestionsVisible())
    {
        clickSearchAreaField();
        Sleeper.sleepTight(CostTestBase.HALF_SECOND);
    }
}
```

And, I want to test it so that the first 2 calls to 'areSearchAreaSuggestionsVisible' return a TRUE, like so:

```
Mockito.when(mockElementState.isElementFoundAndVisible(LandingPage.ADDRESS_SUGGESTIONS, 
  TestBase.ONE_SECOND)).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
```

But, the third call is FALSE.

```
Mockito.when(mockElementState.isElementFoundAndVisible(LandingPage.ADDRESS_SUGGESTIONS, 
  TestBase.ONE_SECOND)).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE);
```

How could I do that with Mockito in one single test method?

Here is my test class so far:

```
@Test
public void testDismissSearchAreaSuggestionsWhenVisible()
{
  Mockito.when(mockElementState.isElementFoundAndVisible(LandingPage.ADDRESS_SUGGESTIONS, 
   CostTestBase.ONE_SECOND)).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
    landingPage.dismissSearchAreaSuggestions();
   Mockito.verify(mockElementState).isElementFoundAndVisible(LandingPage
      .ADDRESS_SUGGESTIONS, CostTestBase.ONE_SECOND);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you make *all of your stubs a part of the same chain*, Mockito will proceed through them in sequence, always repeating the final call.

```
// returns false, false, true, true, true...
when(your.mockedCall(param))'
    .thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE);
```

You can also do so with this syntax...

```
// returns false, false, true, true, true...
when(your.mockedCall(param))
    .thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE)
    .thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE)
    .thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
```

...which can come in handy if the actions aren't all return values.

```
// returns false, false, true, then throws an exception
when(your.mockedCall(param))
    .thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE)
    .thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE)
    .thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE)
    .thenThrow(new Exception("Called too many times!"));
```

If you want things to get more complex than that, consider writing an [Answer](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html).

Comment: That worked!  Thank you very much.     I was trying to put multiple .when lines that but was not working.

Comment: You're welcome! Multiple `when` is treated as overriding your previous stubs, which is particularly useful if you have both general and specific stubs in the same test. _The most recent matching stub chain wins._